# preg_replace not behaving as expected?

Tags: php, regex, xml-parsing, preg-replace

Sup peeps. I got an issue here. I receive this data and just want to strip the `<SOAP-ENV` elements with their respective closing elements.

This is the header and body start part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <VisionDataExchange>
```

Now I run my regular expession on `$xml` the variable containing the entire xml data:

```
$xml = preg_replace("/<\\/?SOAP(.|\\s)*?>/",'',$xml);
```

Now my result is this. It actually stripped the openening tags but none of the closing tags? What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <VisionDataExchange>
```

Comment: Why not speaking SOAP with the remote server? Check [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php)

Comment: the thing is. I don't want to extract the information at all. I just want to remove the soap elements. thats it

Comment: it works https://regex101.com/r/jR6kW5/4

Comment: @AvinashRaj weird. seems to work in the tester but not correct in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just matching everything inside a tag, not `any character or whitespace`. Have a look at [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/nB1hS5/1):

```
$re = "/<\\/?SOAP[^<>]+?>/"; 
$str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">\n  <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>\n  <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n    <VisionDataExchange>"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense, but still yielding same result for me. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after nearly breaking my skull on my desk, i found what the issue was. The regex is indeed working perfectly!there was a hidden `\` in the string that caused the regex to fail.

Comment: The words you use are amazing. "Breaking my skull on my desk" and "Sup peeps". Probably the best entrance and exit I've seen on StackOverflow. `Kudos`